# Store function in data() and execute later

Tags: jquery

I want to store a callback with `data()`. The problem I'm facing is that the function is executing the moment I stored it and I would like to be executed when user clicks

JS

```
function showOnlyOnClick(message)
{
    alert(message);
}

$("button").click(function()
{
    var callback = $(this).data("callback");

    if(callback)
    {
       callback;
    }
});

$("button").data("callback", showOnlyOnClick("not yet!!!"));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ygstvbwj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're immediately calling the `showOnlyOnClick()` function and assigning the *response* from that function call to the `data` attribute.

To fix this you could wrap the call in an anonymous function so that you provide a function *reference* to the `data` attribute which you can call later when the event occurs. Try this:

```js
function showOnlyOnClick(message) {
  alert(message);
}

$("button").click(function() {
  var callback = $(this).data("callback");
  callback && callback();
});

$("button").data("callback", function() {
  showOnlyOnClick("not yet!!!")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showOnlyOnClick(message) {
  alert(message);
}

$("button").click(function() {
  var callback = $(this).data("callback");

  if (callback) {
    callback("on click");
  }
});

$("button").data("callback", showOnlyOnClick);
```

You were executing the function in the last line. You need to store its body.

Comment: While that works, I would need to pass an argument. That callback assignment could be done at several places at different times, Each with a different argument.

Comment: Now that I said it, I think I could attach the arguments in a different data key, right?

Comment: @MatíasCánepa Yes you can do that too.